# INSERT into three tables with many-to-many from one table

Tags: postgresql, database-design, insert, cte, postgresql-9.5

With Postgres 9.5 using a trivial example.
Given I have this data:

Table `everything`:

```
| fruit  | country |
|--------|---------|
| Banana | USA     |
| Banana | Panama  |
```

How would I create these tables?:

Table `fruit`:

```
| fruit_id | name   |
|----------|--------|
| 1        | Banana |
```

Table `country`:

```
| country_id | name   |
|------------|--------|
| 1          | USA    |
| 2          | Panama |
```

Table `fruit_country`:

```
| fruit_id | country_id |
|----------|------------|
| 1        | 1          |
| 1        | 2          |
```

As an initial pass I hoped I could do something like this:

```
WITH fruit_ids AS (
  INSERT INTO fruit(name) (
    SELECT (fruit) FROM everything
  )
  ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
  RETURNING fruit_id
),
country_ids AS (
  INSERT INTO country(name) (
    SELECT(country) FROM everything
  )
    RETURNING country_id
)
INSERT INTO country_fruit(fruit_id, country_id) (
  SELECT
  fruit_id,
  (SELECT country_id FROM country_ids)
  FROM fruit_ids
);
```

But no dice:

> ```
> ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
> ```

Answer (score 4):

The immediate cause for the error message is your abuse of parentheses. But there is more:

Data-modifying CTEs are the wrong tool for the use case. The *UPSERT* (`ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`) indicates that some of the fruits might already exist in table `fruit` (or its use would be nonsense). Hence, some of the fruits might not be included in the set returned with `RETURNING`.

Use simple, separate `INSERT` commands instead. If you need the whole operation to be atomic (all or nothing), wrap it into a transaction.

Also, <strike>`name`</strike> is not a good name for a column. I use `fruit` for fruits and `country` for countries instead. Avoids naming conflicts, and happens to simplify the query a bit by allowing the (totally optional) `USING` clause for the join condition.

Your tables can look like this: (If that was even part of the question?)

```
CREATE TABLE fruit (
   fruit_id serial PRIMARY KEY
 , fruit    text UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE country (
   country_id serial PRIMARY KEY
 , country    text UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE fruit_country (
   fruit_id   int REFERENCES fruit
 , country_id int REFERENCES country
 , PRIMARY KEY (fruit_id, country_id)
);
```

Detailed instructions:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)

To `INSERT` data from `everything`:

```
BEGIN;

INSERT INTO fruit (fruit)
SELECT DISTINCT fruit              -- must be distinct!
FROM   everything
ON     CONFLICT DO NOTHING;

INSERT INTO country (country)
SELECT DISTINCT country            -- must be distinct!
FROM   everything
ON     CONFLICT DO NOTHING;        -- UPSERT here as well

INSERT INTO fruit_country(fruit_id, country_id)
SELECT f.fruit_id, c.country_id
FROM   everything
JOIN   fruit   f USING (fruit)     -- matching row guaranteed now
JOIN   country c USING (country);  -- matching row guaranteed now

COMMIT;
```